# How to recognize if word has no meaning, maybe some impossible syllables?

Tags: cryptography, linguistics, frequency-analysis, text-analysis

Initially, I have **m** arrays of **n** characters, where each array contains unknown (for me) character of needed word (condition: word has meaning).

For example, **m** = 4, **n** = 3: array0 = {'*t*', '*e*', '*c*'}, array1 = {'*g*' '*o*' '*a*'}, array2 = {'*w*' '*d*' '*y*'}, array3 = {'*e*' '*o*' '*s*'}. Each array contains only one correct letter: in array0 is first letter, in array1 - second... So, the probable secret word is '*code*': array0[2] = '*c*', array1[1] = '*o*', array2[1] = '*d*', array3[0] = '*e*'.

I need to find all of existing letter-combinations, i.e. exclude generated meaningless words.
Are there any rules/regularities of 'impossible' syllables/letter-combinations in English?

I'm attacking Vigenere's cipher. So, I know the length of key and its probable characters. I'm shuffling my arrays and getting many meaningless words. Problem is to filter them. As I get it, some conditions can help to recognize incorrect words. For example, if word length is > 4 then all vowel chars, or all consonant chars word is wrong. Some syllables, such as *kk* *hh* *ww*, in general, are impossible too. Where can I find such rules?

Comment: are you doing some security testing?

Comment: I don't think there is a definite rule such that you can say for 100% certain "x" will never come after "z".

Comment: perhaps one can induce that there will always be some case, where "x" comes after "z". Is this post only about the rules or do you want some ways of how to check for simple meaningful words in your arrays? there are lots of possibilities. even in your quite small example!

Comment: You will need a dictionary of english words. From this you can generate all the data you need.

Comment: Have you looked at possibly sending each word to some sort of dictionary service to see if it's found or not? I don't know if speed is a factor in this project or not.

Comment: Speed is not a factor, but MS Word- or Punto Switcher-like apps can process it, so I thought there are some common rules.

Comment: @Aman Most of the dictionaries used in open source kits are relatively simple to parse plain text files. You can download a few of them and test if they suit your needs. Just load the whole shebang into memory, computers should have enough memory for that by now :)

Comment: Hint: work with chances (from `0.0` to `1.0` inclusive) instead of certainties, and try to calculate them over the entire plain text, not just a few words.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing what you mean by the "word has meaning" is that it is an English dictionary word.

I believe that you should approach the problem from the other direction, as GregS suggests, and go through a dictionary. English has many exceptions when it comes to letters and spelling, and the number of words that look English are much greater than the actual number of English words. You won't be able to cut down your search very much in that way.

But because you know the length and probable characters you are able to quickly throw out many dictionary words. Also, if the message isn't too short, it would also be very fast to attempt a decoding of the message with possible words, and throw out unlikely decodings by letter, digram or trigram [frequencies](http://www.cryptograms.org/letter-frequencies.php).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your strategy for attacking a Vigenere cipher. However, in response to:

> I need to find all of existing letter-combinations, i.e. exclude generated meaningless words. Are there any rules/regularities of 'impossible' syllables/letter-combinations in English?

Yes, indeed there is a plethora of such rules. There are two ways of learning and implementing these rules:

1. Carefully study the morphology of English, and meticulously implement the rules.
2. Train a Markov model on a corpus of English text.

1 will be substantially less work for little additional benefit.